# Hightlights dentro do code no github

Tags: github, markdown

Estou fazendo uma documentação (REAMD.md) markdown para ficar muito claro, iniciante, no github.
Quando coloco os códigos, utilizo a sintaxe do código para ressaltar as cores, estético mesmo, a leitura fica melhor.

Mas estou querendo mostrar o passo-a-passo do github dentro do .md

````js
```jsx
para código jsx aqui, por exemplo
```
````

ou

````
```cmd
mkdir teste
cd teste
```
````

tem algum hightlight code para destacar os comandos git init, git push, etc, dentro do markdown do github?

Comment: Talvez o `bash` faça o highlight, voce tentou ele?

Comment: tentei, não rolou =/ , aliás, usei ele e pelo menos as "aspas" que eu coloquei ficaram de outra cor...

Comment: Tente usar `gitattributes`. Aqui tem uma [lista](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml) de possíveis hightlights. Pelo visto, syntax para o `bash` ou `shell` não estão funcionando no github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe um *highlighter* específico para os comandos git, porém você pode utilizar o `gitattributes` (não funciona muito bem com caracteres especiais, no entanto):

[image]

Como os comandos git são na verdade comandos  *shell*, não há problema em utilizar `shell` como *highlighter*:

[image]